# Tablas bloqueadas por transacciones

Tags: mysql, tablas, transacciones

Tengo una base de datos en mysql 5.7 en la cual estamos utilizando procedimientos almacenados y transacciones, el problema que se esta presentado es que las transacciones están bloqueando las tablas que consulta y no permite que otros usuarios las consulten hasta que la transacción activa finalice, actualmente el aislamiento esta en "REPEATABLE READ", ¿Que podemos hacer para solucionar esto?

Comment: Utilizar transacciones solo en los sitios requeridos y hacer commits (o rollbacks) tan pronto sea oportuno.

Comment: Ya no hiciste la misma pregunta anteriormente?

Comment: Porque repetiste la pregunta? tuviste una respuesta y bastantes comentarios para aclararla....